# Trying to patch a method

Tags: python, mocking, patch

I'm trying to start to use the mock library.

So I have a class like this :

class CmdController:

```
def __init__(self):
    pass

def getNbProcessors(self, connParams: ConnectionParams):
    cmd = 'someCommand'
    out, err = self.executeSSHCommand(connParams, cmd)
    if len(err) > 0:
        raise errors.CmdError(err)
    return out

def executeSSHCommand(self, connParams: ConnectionParams, cmd: list) -> tuple:
    <someTreatments>
    return res, err
```

And then I try to test the getNbProcessors function :

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

```
def setUp(self) -> None:
self.connParamsTest = ConnectionParams(some, arguments)

@mock.patch.object('project.Module.CmdController.executeSSHCommand')
def test_getNbProcessors(self, mock_exec_cmd):
    mock_exec_cmd.return_value = '3'
    print(self.cmdController.getNbProcessors(self.connParamsTest))
```

But I get this error :  <module 'project.Module.CmdController' from '/app/SynchroDB_app/project/Module/CmdController.py'> does not have the attribute 'executeSSHCommand'

Can somebody can explain me why he didn't find the method ?

Thanks a lot

I tried to replace 'project.Module.CmdController.executeSSHCommand' with 'CmdController.executeSSHCommand'

Comment: Is CmdController as class or a module? If there exists a module 'project/Module/CmdController.py' which contains a class `CmdController`, you would need to mock it as `project.Module.CmdController.CmdController.executeSSHCommand`.

Comment: It is a class. Thanks for your response, it works that way !

@mock.patch('synchroDB.DataAccess.CmdController.CmdController.executeSSHCommand')
    def test_getNbProcessors(self, mock_exec_cmd):
        mock_exec_cmd.return_value = ('3', [])
       self.assertEqual(self.cmdController.getNbProcessors(self.connParamsCliTest), '3')

Comment: Glad to hear it! I've posted my reply as an answer, please accept it if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `CmdController` is a class in the module 'CmdController.py', it must be referenced as `CmdController.CmdController` when mocking or patching. For example:

```py
@mock.patch.object('project.Module.CmdController.CmdController.executeSSHCommand')
def test_getNbProcessors(self, mock_exec_cmd):
    ...
```